# Linux - Discard keyboard input

Tags: c++, linux, input, keyboard, console

First, a bit of background:  I'm running the latest stable build of Crunchbang Linux inside a VirtualBox VM. I'm designing a custom text-based user interface to run on top of bash.  This is being done with a combination of C++ and bash scripts.

I need to, at times, completely and totally remove the ability for the user to provide the system with any sort of standard keyboard input. This is because, when I run a part of the system, the user is forced to wait for certain amounts of time.
Unfortunately, the user can still type while this is going on, and whatever they type is put on the screen.  This happens when I'm running a C++ program as well as a bash script.  The reason this is a problem is that there is text on the screen which the user is to read, and if they can type, it displaces the text.  There will be other uses for this later, as well, like making the system seem like it has frozen up.

So, the question - How do I

1. disable the keyboard, or
2. prevent anything pressed on the keyboard from showing up on the screen?

Comment: If the answers you get are not satisfying, give more details about the actual interaction of the involved processes. Also, is a "kiosk mode" desired, where the user cannot even leave the terminal or do anything?

Comment: Did you consider using `readline` or `ncurses` library? Did you consider using or customizing some restricted shell (perhaps not `bash`)? What and why exactly are you trying to achieve??

Answer (score 4):

Turn off echo mode with `stty -echo` or the equivalent C code (which would use `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr`). When you are ready to accept input again, turn it back on. You may also wish to discard the input that arrived while you weren't expecting it. That would be done with `tcflush` but be aware that some users (like me) would consider that an annoyance. Typeahead is a feature, not a bug!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This worked exactly how I needed it to.  While typeahead is certainly a feature, it's only a feature so long as it's actually being used as typeahead.  The times when I need it disabled are when there is nothing for the user to be doing.  This is, as much as you can use the term, a game, and having typeahead during simulated processing time, like, say, the time Linux would normally be displaying its boot information, would prove troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

To see how user input to a certain process or tty can be intercepted, the man page and source code of [interceptty](http://www.suspectclass.com/sgifford/interceptty/) may be enlightening. (have no experience with it)

However, you can hardly (totally) prevent user input. The user is probably always able to switch to a different virtual terminal (if any) or at least to reboot the system with Alt+Print+B ([Magic SysRq_key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)) if not disabled. It is two different things to ignore input on a given tty and disabling keyboard input altogether.

Comment: This answer is based on some blatantly wrong ideas. "While a process is running, any keypress is handled by that process and not (automatically) printed on the terminal"? You should read up on how tty's actually work. Hint: run `sleep 30` at your shell prompt. While it's running, type some stuff. It echoes. Do you think the sleep program is doing that?

Comment: Thought a bit about it and adapted... may be just too late over here and time for bed ;)