# User interupts program output C++

Tags: c++

I have written a program that gets user input with `getline()`, and then prints some information to the terminal with several `std::cout`s, with some delay in-between pieces of data. However, if the user types while the output is being printed to the screen, whatever they type will appear, spliced into the output in a very ugly way.

Is there some way to stop user input from being written to the screen, while still using the terminal?

Edit: This is different from "how to prevent overtyping", as that question is about preventing the program output from breaking the user's input, and this question is about preventing the user's input from breaking the program's output. They are different enough that none of the answers to that question would work for this one, unfortunately (Except maybe writing a GUI).

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223736/linux-discard-keyboard-input) answered my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    timespec* interval= new timespec;
    interval->tv_sec=1;

    termios t_echo;
    termios t_noecho;
    tcgetattr(0,&t_noecho);
    tcgetattr(0,&t_echo);

    t_noecho.c_lflag&= ~ECHO;

    while(true)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin,input);
        tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&t_noecho);
        std::cout<<input<<std::endl;

        std::cout<<"output1"<<std::endl;
        nanosleep(interval,interval);
        std::cout<<"output2"<<std::endl;
        nanosleep(interval,interval);
        std::cout<<"output3"<<std::endl;
        nanosleep(interval,interval);//prevents typeahead

        tcflush(0,TCIFLUSH);
        tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&t_echo);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is closed as duplicate of a wrong question (with Windows-specific answers). Better duplicate is linked by in the question edit, should be opened and re-closed.

Comment: I agree. The question I linked will be more helpful to others with this same issue in the future.